# MySQL auto increment column

Tags: mysql, innodb

I see a weird behavior where my auto-increment column number is only increasing in a step of 2 instead of 1. So I end up with row ids as 1, 3, 5, 7. I use MySQL 5.6 + InnoDB as the engine. Any idea why this weirdness?

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------------+
| version()       |
+-----------------+
| 5.6.20-68.0-log |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table temp_table;
| superset_version | CREATE TABLE `temp_table` (
  `_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'comm1',
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'comm2',
  `start_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'comm3',
  `updated_at` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'comm4',
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'comm5',
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Notice that insert incremented the `_id` column by a difference of 2.

```
mysql> insert into superset_version(name, start_time, updated_at, status) value("TEMP ROW", -1, -1, "erro");
    Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from superset_version order by _id desc limit 3;
+-----+----------+------------+------------+--------+
| _id | name     | start_time | updated_at | status |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+--------+
|  33 | TEMP ROW |         -1 |         -1 | erro   |
|  31 | TEMP ROW |         -1 |         -1 | erro   |
|  29 | TEMP ROW |         -1 |         -1 | erro   |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: *"1 warning"* ... `mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;`

Comment: Oops, I had swapped columns earlier in my insert and pasted that version but then I realized and corrected the insert statement but forgot to paste the correct output. Rest assured the above statement gives no warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) setting is most likely set to 2, therefore mysql increases auto increment numbers by 2. Use [show varibles like ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-variables.html) command to check the setting.

Comment: Thats true! ```mysql> show variables like 'auto_increment_increment';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 2     |
+--------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)```

Comment: And that could be because of having a "dual-master" setup and writing to both Masters.  (A dangerous setup.)

Answer (score 1):

for double check you could try:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
From `information_schema`.`TABLES`
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = '<<YOUR TABLE NAME HERE>>' AND
TABLE_SCHEMA = '<< YOUR DATABASE NAME HERE >>'
```

if the step is really equals 2, it's possible to replace it.

or one another way:
Check values in:
mysql.cnf / ini:

```
auto-increment-increment
auto-increment-offset
```